# Jenkins: how to make parameters required in a parameterized build?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

In Jenkins is there a plugin for parameterized builds to make the parameters required?  The fields under the standard "This build is parameterized" option do not seem to provide that.

Clarification: by "required" I mean that the build will not execute until the field is populated with a value.  This would obviously preclude automated triggers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the plugin i use to do this type of stuff: [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Validating+String+Parameter+Plugin)...
You can set a regular expression to validate the input against

Comment: Actually, that plugin only shows a failure message in the parameter form if the parameter does not pass validation, but you can still trigger a build with invalid parameters.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer is no longer valid.

There was a [plugin that did that](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Validating+String+Parameter+Plugin) but is no longer maintained.

There's an [open bug to support it](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3509).

In the mean time what you can do is check if your parameter is present and if not throw an error like:

```
if (!params.SomeParam) {
    error("Build failed because of this and that..")
}
```

Comment: this is indeed a good comment, that validation script, where would one place it?

Comment: @MiguelCosta creating a step which the first thing it does is that validation. otherwise it will not continue.

Answer (score 20):

Couldn't comment to answer Miguel's question, so answering here:

To fail a build if a parameter is not set, one could do something like this:

```
stage('Checkout') 
    {
        steps
        {
            checkout scm
            script 
            {
                if (params.myParam == '') { // and/or whatever condition you want
                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                    error('myParam not set')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin called "Validating String Parameter". When you install this plugin in your project, you see an additional option of Validating String Parameter while adding parameters. Using this option will show an additional column of Regular expression.
For non-empty string parameter write this inside Regular Expression field:

```
^(?!\s*$).+
```

This will finally make your string parameter mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case then IMHO `when {}` is currently the best solution to this problem. Just skip all stages when the parameters aren't set correctly and do the validation/aborting/triggering error of each parameter required within `steps{}` then or just let the command there failing.

Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'FOO', defaultValue: '', description: 'FUBAR', trim: true)
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    triggeredBy 'BuildUpstreamCause'
                    expression { return params.FOO }
                }
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    if (params.FOO.length() < 8) {
                        error("Parameter FOO must be at least 8 chars")
                    }
                }

                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's of cause a bit annoying when you need to do this on multiple steps, but at least you can move it into a function:

```
def stageWhen() {
    return (triggeredBy('BuildUpstreamCause') || params.FOO)
}

def validateParameterFoo() {
    if (params.FOO.length() < 8) {
        error("Parameter FOO must be at least 8 chars")
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    
    parameters {
        string(name: 'FOO', defaultValue: '', description: 'FUBAR', trim: true)
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            when {
                expression { return stageWhen() }
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    validateParameterFoo()
                }

                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Test 2') {
            when {
                expression { return stageWhen() }
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    validateParameterFoo()
                }

                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```