# Mandatory Jenkins parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to know how to make a parameter mandatory in Jenkins, so the "Build" button is unavailable until someone fills it.

```
[$class: 'hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Description', name: 'repositoryTag'],
```

I have this, and I was wondering if there is something I could do such as adding "required: True" for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins: how to make parameters required in a parameterized build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742401/jenkins-how-to-make-parameters-required-in-a-parameterized-build)

Comment: Unfortunately no - I cannot install plugins, and I was wondering if there was any other way than throwing an error or forcing to a defaultValue if it is equal to null/empty string